# Resultados de una function en un DataFrame en python

Tags: python, funciones, pandas

Tengo una función en python que usa valores de dos columnas etiquetadas como `'POSITION_X'` y `'POSITION_Y'` en un archivo .csv (df1)

La función calcula la suma `|Xn-Xn+N|+|Yn-Yn+N|` donde `n` es el numero de fila y `N` es la separación entre las filas.

El código luce así:

```
df1 = df[['TRACK_ID','POSITION_X','POSITION_Y','POSITION_T']].copy

def radial(df1, coords=['POSITION_X', 'POSITION_Y']): 
        tau = t.copy()
        shifts = np.floor(tau / t_step).astype(np.int)

        for i, shift in enumerate(shifts):
            diffs = df1[coords] - df1[coords].shift(-shift)
            sqdist = np.square(diffs).sum(axis=1)
            r = np.sqrt(sqdist)
            print(r)

        radial_disp = pd.DataFrame(data=r)

        return radial_disp

radial_d = radial (df1, frames, coords=['POSITION_X', 'POSITION_Y'])
print(radial_d)
```

Como es de esperarse el resultado es un enorme numero de sumas en muchas columnas, el problema es que puedo ver los resultados cuando imprimo `r` pero el `dataFrame` que genera solo muestra la última suma, que de hecho es cero. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para alojar todos mis resultados de `r` en un data frame?

El ejemplo de lo que quiero es el siguiente:

para un df1

```
df1=
  X 
 10
 15
 25
 30`
```

el resultado seria:

```
`N1   N2
 5    15
 10   15
 5    NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es al hacer esto:

```
for i, shift in enumerate(shifts):
    diffs = df1[coords] - df1[coords].shift(-shift)
    sqdist = np.square(diffs).sum(axis=1)
    r = np.sqrt(sqdist)
    print(r)

radial_disp = pd.DataFrame(data=r)
```

`r` se inicializa con cada ciclo del `for` por consiguiente al salir del bucle lo que vas a obtener el el último de los valores calculados. Deberías ir "acumulando" los valores de r por ejemplo en una lista

```
r = []
for i, shift in enumerate(shifts):
    diffs = df1[coords] - df1[coords].shift(-shift)
    sqdist = np.square(diffs).sum(axis=1)
    r.append(np.sqrt(sqdist))
```

Comment: Funciona,  Muchas gracias!!